# What is the type of Nothing in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm at page [118](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#type-parameters) of the book "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!"

It is written there:

```
ghci> :t Nothing 
Nothing :: Maybe a
```

Here is my question:

If I understand correctly, `Nothing` is a value and only concrete types can have values, but `Maybe a` is not a concrete type. So how can it have the value `Nothing`?

The book also says:

> Notice that the type of Nothing is Maybe a. Its type is polymorphic.

What does polymorphic type mean? How should I understand this? Is this not in contradiction with the rule that only concrete types can have values?

EDIT:

From the PDF version of the book :

> We say that a type is concrete if it doesn't take any type parameters
>   at all (like Int or Bool), or if it takes type parameters and they're
>   all filled up (like Maybe Char). If you have some value, its type is
>   always a concrete type.

Comment: Pretty interesting question. Nothing is not a value, but constructor. Constructor is a function (well, not exactly) which is a value of _certain_ type.

Comment: Function is a value of a certain type? How should I understand this? Could you please explain what you mean by this in some more detail?

Comment: `Maybe` is not a concrete type and can't have values. `Maybe a` is a concrete type for any `a`. `Nothing` is a value for `Maybe a` for any `a`.

Comment: The book defines "concrete type" to mean "fully applied type constructor", or more formally, type of kind `*`. This is what seems to be causing all the confusion. According to the book's definition `Maybe a` is concrete, and `Maybe` alone is not. So there's absolutely no problem with `Nothing` being of type `Maybe a`. That being said, "concrete" is in no way an official term, and everybody uses it differently.

Comment: This is a little bit subtle, and I am far from the most knowledgeable person here on this, but I do believe that in the language underlying Haskell (a variant of lambda calculus), `Nothing` is really of type `/\a. Maybe a`, meaning that if you give it a concrete type `a` you get a value of the concrete type `Maybe a`.  However, this passing of the type `a` is implicit in Haskell.

Comment: So this means that there exist types that are not concrete? Maybe alone is a not concrete type? I thought Maybe alone is not a type at all but a type constructor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not in contradiction. `Nothing` is a value, and its concrete type may be any possible instantiation of `Maybe a`.

Otherwise said, values of type `Maybe a` continue to have concrete types `Maybe Int`, `Maybe String`, `Maybe Whatever`, and in particular, `Nothing` is able to be typed by each of them, depending on the context. That's because its constructor, which is again called `Nothing :: Maybe a`, does not take any parameters and therefore it can be called as-is to generate values of type `Maybe a`. We will have one per concrete type, if you wish.

Without a context, of course ghci will give you the most general type it can infer for `Nothing`, which is `Maybe a`, but it's not its concrete type. That will depend on the individual expressions you will use `Nothing` in. E.g.:

```
ghci> Nothing
Nothing
it :: Maybe a
```

This is what you probably typed, or something like that. There is no further context, therefore `Nothing` doesn't get typed with a concrete type.

```
ghci> Nothing :: Maybe Int
Nothing
it :: Maybe Int
```

Here I forced it to assume the concrete type `Maybe Int`.

```
ghci> 1 + fromMaybe 2 Nothing
3
it :: Integer
```

If I mix it with a sum of integers (`fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a` takes a default value and a `Maybe a` and returns either the value in the `Just` or the default with `Nothing`), then `Nothing` will get typed as `Maybe Integer` by the system, since you expect to extract an integer from it. There's none, so in this case we sum 1 with the default 2.

```
ghci> 1 + fromMaybe 2 (Nothing :: Maybe Integer)
3
it :: Integer
```

Same here, to double check. We force `Nothing` to have the concrete type we assumed it had before in the same expression.

```
ghci> 1 + fromMaybe 2 (Nothing :: Maybe Char)

<interactive>:1:15:
    No instance for (Num Char)
      arising from the literal `2'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num Char)
    In the first argument of `fromMaybe', namely `2'
    In the second argument of `(+)', namely
      `fromMaybe 2 (Nothing :: Maybe Char)'
    In the expression: 1 + fromMaybe 2 (Nothing :: Maybe Char)
```

To triple-check, if we force it to assume another concrete type, as you see its value will be completely different, resulting in a type error (unlike C, in Haskell `Char` doesn't act as a number).

Comment: The GHCI says that the type of Nothing is Maybe a, but what is Maybe a ?

Comment: According to user3974 Nothing is not a value but a constructor... hmmm.

Comment: So Nothing has no concrete type in itself? Then what kind of type does Nothing have? How are these kind of types called?

Comment: ...polymorphic :) Exactly like `Just :: a -> Maybe a` is a polymorphic constructor.

Comment: I think there is some doubt about the word 'concrete'. I have more often seen the word 'concrete' used to mean 'ground type', i.e. type of Kind *. In this sense, "Maybe a" is perfectly concrete - it's a ground type just polymorphic. Here you are using concrete to mean monomorphic. I think part of the OP's confusion is these two unrelated senses of the word 'concrete'. The excerpts the OP quotes from LYAH are using 'concrete' in the 'having Kind *' sense.

Answer (score 6):

> Is this not in contradiction with the rule the only concrete types can have values?

Since functions are first-class values in Haskell, this purported rule would mean that polymorphic functions such as `map` and `foldr` would be impossible to implement.

There are, in fact, a lot of polymorphic non-function values in Haskell, such as

```
1 :: Num a => a
Nothing :: Maybe a
[] :: [a]
Left 1 :: Num a => Either a b
```

etc. These values exist for every instantiation of `a` (and `b`).

Comment: So the conclusion is that not only concrete types can have values? So the book's statement (please see EDIT) is incorrect? So 'Maybe a' is a polymorphic type (i.e. not concrete type) then, do I understand that correctly? Is 'polymorphic type' the correct terminology to denote concepts like 'Maybe a'?

Comment: @jhegedus It looks like the book was referring to concrete meaning fully applied. `forall a. Maybe a` is a fully applied type which can absolutely have values. `Maybe` is not and so there is no value `v :: Maybe`

Comment: So the conclusion is that the type of Nothing is Maybe a ?

Comment: @jhegedus: Yes (just as GHC said).

Answer (score 3):

In some sense, you're right. There are no values of type `forall a.Maybe a`. Every Maybe value you construct will actually have some definite type `Maybe tau`, where `tau` may be known or not, but is some definite type.

The notation `Nothing :: forall a.Maybe a` just tells us that whenever we use the expression `Nothing`, it will construct a value of the expected `Maybe` type.

Comment: What is `forall a.Maybe a` ? I am only at page 118 of the Haskell book, so unfortunately I am not Haskell expert.

Comment: @jhegedus I told you above: in this case it means "whatever concrete Maybe type you want, this will make it for you". Or, mor formally: forall a you could want, `Nothing` will give you `Maybe a`. That is, if you want a `Maybe String`, `Nothing` will give you a `Maybe String`. And the same for `Int` or whatever.

Comment: Of course polymorphic types have values. And `Nothing` is a value of type `forall a. Maybe a` as much as `\ x -> x` is a value of type `forall a. a -> a`.

Comment: @kosmikus Well, I suggest you show me some code where an expression `Nothing` is alledgedly used at type forall a.Maybe a, and I'll tell you the real type of that Nothing, and it won't be forall a. Maybe a

Comment: @Ingo ... or `const False Nothing`

Comment: @kosmikus `const :: forall a b. a -> b -> a` is here instantiatet at type `Bool -> Maybe tb -> Bool`. And `tb` is **some monomorphic** type, not "any type". This often gets confused.

Comment: @Ingo Alright, while I think this distinction doesn't make sense in a language like Haskell which on the surface has no explicit type application, then what about `let f :: (forall a. Maybe a) -> Bool; f _ = True in f Nothing` ?

Comment: @kosmikus This time you got me :) But this already requires higher rank types, doesn't it.

Comment: @Ingo Sure it does. But I don't see basis for the claim that the type `forall a. Maybe a` has no values even without that extension enabled. I think that even just wrapping `Nothing` up and defining `x :: Maybe a; x = Nothing` would qualify.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48578/discussion-between-kosmikus-and-ingo)

Answer (score 1):

The Maybe type has two constructors: Nothing and Just a, where a is a type variable. Nothing itself does not determine (constrain) the type, but in any reasonable context you'll find something like (I do not claim it to be syntactically correct Haskell but something I would have written 10 years ago):

```
if (foo == 5)
then Nothing
else Just 5
```

And then type inference will tell you that (assume 5 was an argument to this code snippet 'foo' of type Int) that foo has type:

```
foo :: Int -> Maybe Int
```

But as the previous poster pointed out, Maybe a is a perfectly good type. You'll find the same non-issue with [] ie the list type with [] (the constructor for an empty list).

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLj1QV11o9g) talk at 26:00 answers the question: "what is the type of `[ ]`?" which is a related question to "what is the type of `Nothing`?".

Also Hudak's book has a nice paragraph on this  :

[image]